# Should I wait before flagging as "Unclear what you're asking"?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging

Sometimes it’s unclear what a user is asking to understand questions properly. I had flagged such questions as "Unclear what you're asking" and all deemed helpful also.

Should I give time to the user to clarify their question by commenting on it? Or is it OK to flag that type of question directly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Should I give time to user to clear it's question by commenting on it?

You should do both ASAP, without waiting. Comment and flag. That way if they don't improve their question it gets closed (since it's unanswerable and even if someone answers when OP edit it may invalidate answers it may have) and if they do improve the close voters will vote to leave open (if they aren't rubber stamping :/) or if he edits in the first 5 days of being closed it will get in the reopen review queue. That's The Right Way™.

Comment: I'd also add that if the question is closed and the OP edits it, it automatically jumps in the reopen queue.

Answer (score -4):

The first step, is to ask. The question may not be clear to you - but it may be clear to others. This means watching the activity on the question.

I find this site too heavily mod'ed. I've downgraded this site, and use it only to get an overview of a problem or issue. Much like Wikipedia, it's good for general use, but not for serious work. I come here to see the size of an issue (just me or others). Once the question is answered, I move to other more effective sites.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  :)

Comment: I agree with the first paragraph. I have in the past answered questions that were perhaps awkwardly phrased but made enough sense to me, even though they were marked as "unclear".

Comment: @SyborgiaAlphas What is mean by "I've downgraded this site"?